# How do you import a json file to excel with tree-references?

Tags: json, excel, powershell, import

I have a .json file that has around 8 Megabyte of data, containing multiple HashSets from Powershell with the Command:

```
$Hashset = @{"ChildHashset" = @{"ChildOfChildHashset" = @{...} ,... }, ...}

$Hashset | Convertto-Json | out-file "C:\...\file.json"
```

I want to work with the Json-File in Excel, so I Need the Parent-Level to be in a seperate Table, as the Child-Level.

As I tried to Import the .json file, The Values of the Hashset-Names were [Record] without a reference.
Additionally I had to manually click on every record, Excel has shown, to generate a Table from it.

Is there a Method to simple Input the .Json-File, and generate multiple Excel-Tables with designated Name & Reference to previous Data-Value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the json file via: `$json Object = Get-Content file.json | convertfrom-json`. Regarding Excel you can check this link https://somoit.net/powershell/powershell-excel-spreadsheet-mini-tutorial

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to work with `$Hashset` in csv than JSON.